Analysis of Variance Assumption Testing When Multiple Error Terms Are Used
I am conducting a repeated-measures analysis in R, where blocks were sampled repeatedly over a season.
My_Data <- data.frame(Sampling_Date = rep(1:4, each = 12), 
                      Block = rep(1:3, length.out = 48), 
                      Treatment = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3, 
                                  length.out = 48), 
                      Response = abs(rnorm(48, 10, 1)))
Model <- aov(Response ~ (Treatment * as.factor(Sampling_Date)) + 
    Error(as.factor(Block) / (Treatment * as.factor(Sampling_Date))), 
    data = My_Data)
summary(Model)

I want to see if the assumptions of normality of residuals and homogeneity of variances are met. I can't run these assumption tests in R like I normally do, though, because the model output has different tables for different error terms. For example, the Shapiro-Wilk test takes residuals as its input, and in this case, I have multiple different sets of residuals (one for each model output table). I have the same problem when I try to use Levene's test for variance homogeneity.
Should I run these tests for each model output table separately?
lapply(Model, function (x) {
  shapiro.test(x$residuals)
})

I'm getting a sample-size error here, but for the sake of my question, I'm really just wondering what the most appropriate way to run these tests is.
